# Autocompleting/expanding text in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, autocomplete

I'm creating a technical document using Microsoft Word 2010 in Windows 7. I have various pieces of long technical terminology that I regularly use, and typing this jargon manually hundreds of times would significantly increase the time I spend writing the document.

I was looking for a way to add custom autocompletion entries in Word so that whenever I typed a trigger word or abbreviation for a given technical term, Word expanded the text to the full term. I worked out how to do this, and decided it'd be worth writing up the answer to SU because of how relatively hidden away it is - for me, at least.

*This is useful for any pieces of text that often need to be repeated in a document, such as the name of a company or brand in legal documentation, a historical figure in an essay, or a company or email address in professional correspondence.*

**How can I have Word automatically expand to a word or phrase whenever I type a trigger word or abbreviation for it?**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this in Microsoft Word is using the *AutoCorrect* feature. This feature was present in Word 2003, but was removed from Word 2007, only to be reintroduced in Word 2010. Word 2007 uses *AutoText* instead, which is a little more clunky to setup and is triggered by <kbd>F3</kbd> instead of the spacebar, but does more or less the same thing.

Follow the guides below based on the version of Word you're working with.

## For Microsoft Word 2003, Microsoft Word 2010 and onwards

This is done using Word 2010's native AutoCorrect.

1. From the Ribbon/menu, click on **File**, then **Options**.
2. In the window that appears, select the **Proofing** tab.
3. Click the **AutoCorrect Options** button.
4. In the window that appears, the cursor will be focused on the *Replace* field. Enter the text that you'd like to use as a trigger word or abbreviation.

[image]

5. In the *With* field, enter the text that you want the trigger to expand to, and then click **Add**. You can add as many autocomplete expansions as you need in this way, as well as modify the default expansions. Click **OK**, then **OK** again to return to the document.
6. Finally, type the trigger that you entered for the word, and press the spacebar to see Word expand it.

## For Microsoft Word 2007

Because the *AutoCorrect* feature no longer exists in Word 2007, you'll need to use the *AutoText* feature instead. The process to do this is a little more involved, but ultimately allows for the same end result.

1. From the Ribbon/menu, click on `File`, then `Options`.
2. Select the `Customize` tab.
3. In the *Choose commands from* dropdown menu, select `Commands Not in the Ribbon`.

[image]

4. Scroll down the list of commands until you find the *AutoText* command. Select the command, and click `Add` to add it to the ribbon. Click `OK` to save and exit out of the options window. You'll see that an `AutoText` button has been added to the very top of the Ribbon.
5. To create a new AutoText entry, write out the text that you want to expand to, select it, and click the `AutoText` button added in the previous step.
6. At the bottom of the dropdown window that appears, click `Save Selection to AutoText Gallery`. This will take you to a window called *Create New Building Block*. Building Blocks are the items that AutoText uses to autocomplete words.

[image]

8. Replace the *Name* field with the text that you'd like to use as a trigger for the autocomplete, then click `OK` to return to the document.
9. Finally, type the trigger for your word into the document, then press <kbd>F3</kbd> to expand it.